# Update Table Values in array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I Have a Table then I Want Update Table Values in Array. Using corresponding id.I'm Using `REPLACE INTO` but all Rows Update Every Time. So I Don't Want. I have Only Update If Any Value Changes in Array that Transaction ID.(Sorry My Bad Language)
see my example

```
$tbtransaction = array(
    array(
        "TransactionID" => 16,
        "VoucherType" => "Cash Payment",
        "AccName" => "OFFICE EXPENSE",
        "Particulars" => "CASH ACCOUNT",
        "Debit" => 2000,
        "Credit" => 50,
    ),
    array(
        "TransactionID" => 17,
        "VoucherType" => "Cash Payment",
        "AccName" => "OFFICE EXPENSE",
        "Particulars" => "CASH ACCOUNT",
        "Debit" => 1250,
        "Credit" => 350,
    ),
    array(
        "TransactionID" => 18
        ,
        "VoucherType" => "Bank Payment",
        "AccName" => "Simple EXPENSE",
        "Particulars" => "CASH ACCOUNT",
        "Debit" => 410,
        "Credit" => 0,
    ),
    array(
        "TransactionID" => 19,
        "VoucherType" => "Cash Payment",
        "AccName" => "OFFICE EXPENSE",
        "Particulars" => "CASH ACCOUNT",
        "Debit" => 2000,
        "Credit" => 0,
    ),
    array(
        "TransactionID" => 20,
        "VoucherType" => "Cash Payment",
        "AccName" => "OFFICE EXPENSE",
        "Particulars" => "CASH ACCOUNT",
        "Debit" => 25,
        "Credit" => 40,
    ),

);
```

Transaction Table

```
TransactionID   VoucherType    AccName          Particulars    Debit  Credit
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16           Cash Payment   OFFICE EXPENSE     CASH ACCOUNT    2000     50
17           Cash Payment   OFFICE EXPENSE     CASH ACCOUNT    1250     300
18           BankPayment    OTHER EXPENSE      OTHER ACCOUNT   410      10
19           Cash Payment   TRAVEL EXPENSE     BANK ACCOUNT    300       0
20           Cash Payment   OFFICE EXPENSE     CASH ACCOUNT    25       40
```

Comment: You should first fetch the item from the DB and then compare them to the one you have in the array (use `array_intersect`) and then update only them

Comment: or may be you can apply foreach with update command where you use child-array data to update the table record for corresponding `id`, if there will be any change that will saved otherwise it will continue for next child array

Comment: @AlivetoDie How to Use this in `foreach` I used But I cant Properly Please Please Give Some Example

Comment: @bluemeadia  something like this:- `foreach( $tbtransaction as $tbtransact ){
   
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE <table name> SET `VoucherType`=? ,`AccName`=?,`Particulars`=?,`Debit`=?,`Credit`=? WHERE `TransactionID`=?");
 $stmt->bind_param('sssiii',$tbtransact['VoucherType'], $tbtransact['AccName'], $tbtransact['Particulars'], $tbtransact['Debit'],$tbtransact['Credit'],$tbtransact['TransactionID']);
 $stmt->execute();
}` . You can use example for `mysqli` code from this thread for code help:- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php